# Mathematica - Dynamic - ListPlot - baseline

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I am performing baseline fitting to a raw dataset on a two-state equilibrium process.  The process involves fitting the sigmoidal curve to an upper and lower linear baseline, and subtracting so that you get a curve going from y=(0) (state 1) to y=(1) (state 2) over your x-value range instead y=(experimental observable values).

I'd like to expedite the baseline selection process through an interactive dynamic approach rather than manually typing in lhs/rhs x-values for each curve.  However, I'm noticing that the dynamic values behind the dynamic plots need to be on the screen for the plot to update.  Meaning, if I'm dynamic listplotting 4 points, and only three of these dynamic values (the output) are on screen then only three show up.  I have to scroll up or down through the notebook to "update" various values and then the plots correct themselves.

I have many calculations downstream after baseline selection, and I'd like to have all these subsequent calculations print up in a neat little grid near the sliders, without have to scroll.

I'm new to Dynamic, and also having trouble combining multiple plots (similar to Show) when held under the Dynamic functions.  I'd like to dynamically in one graphic plot the ListPlot of my rawData, the four baseline points, and then the fitted linear function through the selected rawData in the baseline area.  Next to this, I'll plot the two-state equilibrium plot (y=0 to 1) and then a single point representing the transition point of 50/50 state1/state2 (y=0.5).  All of these downstream processes are highly dependent on baseline selection, so I'd like to have the slider there and final plots to immediately see the results of various choices for baselines.

In summary, two questions:
1) screen refresh needed of output from dynamic values for updating dynamic plots not in the same input section
2) multiple plot types within a single graphic, dynamically

```
ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[
   1] = {{5.2, 171.5576923076923}, {5.4, 171.4583916083916}, {5.6, 
    171.36804195804197}, {5.8, 171.31552447552448}, {6, 
    171.31125874125877}, {6.2, 171.35321678321677}, {6.4, 
    171.41783216783216}, {6.6, 171.5072027972028}, {6.8, 
    171.61223776223778}, {7, 171.74020979020978}, {7.2, 
    171.8802097902098}, {7.4, 172.01412587412588}, {7.6, 
    172.1367832167832}, {7.8, 172.25818181818184}, {8, 
    172.37916083916082}, {8.2, 172.52223776223775}, {8.4, 
    172.65797202797202}, {8.6, 172.81475524475525}, {8.8, 
    172.97706293706293}, {9, 173.16314685314686}, {9.2, 
    173.35531468531468}, {9.4, 173.56958041958043}, {9.6, 
    173.7951048951049}, {9.8, 174.03153846153847}, {10, 
    174.2748951048951}, {10.2, 174.51762237762236}, {10.4, 
    174.7634265734266}, {10.6, 174.9851048951049}, {10.8, 
    175.1865034965035}, {11, 175.3864335664336}, {11.2, 
    175.59503496503498}, {11.4, 175.81916083916082}, {11.6, 
    176.02797202797203}, {11.8, 176.2442657342657}, {12, 
    176.45391608391608}, {12.2, 176.6886013986014}, {12.4, 
    176.9281118881119}, {12.6, 177.19}, {12.8, 177.47}, {13, 
    177.7390909090909}, {13.2, 178.01503496503494}, {13.4, 
    178.2923076923077}, {13.6, 178.60461538461539}, {13.8, 
    178.92685314685315}, {14, 179.24713286713288}, {14.2, 
    179.5781818181818}, {14.4, 179.93076923076922}, {14.6, 
    180.32083916083917}, {14.8, 180.71741258741258}, {15, 
    181.124965034965}, {15.2, 181.55125874125875}, {15.4, 
    181.97825174825175}, {15.6, 182.41020979020982}, {15.8, 
    182.8441258741259}, {16, 183.3011188811189}, {16.2, 
    183.77636363636367}, {16.4, 184.26951048951048}, {16.6, 
    184.80447552447555}, {16.8, 185.37951048951047}, {17, 
    185.97846153846154}, {17.2, 186.58356643356643}, {17.4, 
    187.19545454545454}, {17.6, 187.81587412587407}, {17.8, 
    188.44538461538463}, {18, 189.08426573426573}, {18.2, 
    189.73111888111887}, {18.4, 190.38111888111888}, {18.6, 
    191.04258741258744}, {18.8, 191.7199300699301}, {19, 
    192.43076923076922}, {19.2, 193.16111888111888}, {19.4, 
    193.91048951048953}, {19.6, 194.68713286713282}, {19.8, 
    195.4913286713287}, {20, 196.32006993006993}, {20.2, 
    197.17510489510488}, {20.4, 198.05881118881118}, {20.6, 
    198.95755244755247}, {20.8, 199.8584615384615}, {21, 
    200.76384615384615}, {21.2, 201.68461538461537}, {21.4, 
    202.62685314685316}, {21.6, 203.66496503496504}, {21.8, 
    204.81300699300698}, {22, 205.96062937062936}, {22.2, 
    206.8897902097902}, {22.4, 207.50202797202797}, {22.6, 
    207.81699300699304}, {22.8, 207.95888111888112}, {23, 
    208.02839160839162}, {23.2, 208.14692307692306}, {23.4, 
    208.4265734265734}, {23.6, 208.94608391608392}, {23.8, 
    209.81937062937064}, {24, 211.1255244755245}, {24.2, 
    212.82013986013985}, {24.4, 214.7145454545455}, {24.6, 
    216.61958041958042}, {24.8, 218.50860139860137}, {25, 
    220.42069930069928}, {25.2, 222.4111888111888}, {25.4, 
    224.48314685314682}, {25.6, 226.616013986014}, {25.8, 
    228.8025874125874}, {26, 231.0102097902098}, {26.2, 
    233.26111888111888}, {26.4, 235.54636363636362}, {26.6, 
    237.8906293706294}, {26.8, 240.30881118881118}, {27, 
    242.80363636363634}, {27.2, 245.37720279720278}, {27.4, 
    248.0467132867133}, {27.6, 250.82118881118885}, {27.8, 
    253.69622377622377}, {28, 256.65937062937064}, {28.2, 
    259.7168531468531}, {28.4, 262.8809090909091}, {28.6, 
    266.136083916084}, {28.8, 269.48853146853145}, {29, 
    272.9494405594406}, {29.2, 276.5634265734266}, {29.4, 
    280.31496503496504}, {29.6, 284.1983916083916}, {29.8, 
    288.2063636363637}, {30, 292.3523076923077}, {30.2, 
    296.6392307692308}, {30.4, 301.0708391608391}, {30.6, 
    305.62391608391613}, {30.8, 310.3113286713287}, {31, 
    315.11034965034963}, {31.2, 320.04965034965034}, {31.4, 
    325.1569230769231}, {31.6, 330.4420979020979}, {31.8, 
    335.90902097902097}, {32, 341.55034965034963}, {32.2, 
    347.37482517482516}, {32.4, 353.38538461538457}, {32.6, 
    359.5694405594406}, {32.8, 365.93888111888117}, {33, 
    372.4761538461538}, {33.2, 379.2182517482518}, {33.4, 
    386.1609790209791}, {33.6, 393.32629370629365}, {33.8, 
    400.7041958041958}, {34, 408.26265734265735}, {34.2, 
    416.02657342657346}, {34.4, 423.96489510489516}, {34.6, 
    432.1181818181819}, {34.8, 440.4820979020979}, {35, 
    448.6806293706294}, {35.2, 456.86342657342664}, {35.4, 
    465.53755244755246}, {35.6, 475.66034965034964}, {35.8, 
    487.5865734265734}, {36, 501.1653146853147}, {36.2, 
    516.0813286713288}, {36.4, 531.9086013986014}, {36.6, 
    548.2587412587412}, {36.8, 564.6713986013987}, {37, 
    580.6118881118881}, {37.2, 595.7270629370629}, {37.4, 
    609.4006293706293}, {37.6, 622.2286013986014}, {37.8, 
    634.5355944055943}, {38, 647.2777622377623}, {38.2, 
    660.156153846154}, {38.4, 673.3221678321679}, {38.6, 
    686.4862237762237}, {38.8, 699.9664335664336}, {39, 
    713.5155244755244}, {39.2, 727.4389510489511}, {39.4, 
    741.0336363636363}, {39.6, 755.0702097902098}, {39.8, 
    769.5217482517482}, {40, 785.5246153846156}, {40.2, 
    802.3835664335664}, {40.4, 820.4558741258742}, {40.6, 
    838.8953146853147}, {40.8, 858.1897202797202}, {41, 
    877.5658741258741}, {41.2, 897.573986013986}, {41.4, 
    917.3868531468532}, {41.6, 937.4052447552448}, {41.8, 
    956.7482517482517}, {42, 976.6904895104893}, {42.2, 
    997.0346153846153}, {42.4, 1018.8477622377623}, {42.6, 
    1041.1142657342657}, {42.8, 1064.3213286713287}, {43, 
    1088.1560139860142}, {43.2, 1112.473986013986}, {43.4, 
    1137.4900699300697}, {43.6, 1164.0341958041959}, {43.8, 
    1192.6026573426573}, {44, 1223.4609090909091}, {44.2, 
    1255.9941258741258}, {44.4, 1290.8709790209791}, {44.6, 
    1327.0130769230768}, {44.8, 1364.6239860139858}, {45, 
    1402.7880419580417}, {45.2, 1442.381118881119}, {45.4, 
    1482.7290909090907}, {45.6, 1523.66013986014}, {45.8, 
    1565.570979020979}, {46, 1609.5718881118883}, {46.2, 
    1656.1732867132866}, {46.4, 1705.5791608391607}, {46.6, 
    1757.082797202797}, {46.8, 1811.405664335664}, {47, 
    1867.7601398601398}, {47.2, 1927.0214685314686}, {47.4, 
    1988.903566433566}, {47.6, 2053.9727272727273}, {47.8, 
    2121.3558741258735}, {48, 2191.253076923077}, {48.2, 
    2263.4567132867137}, {48.4, 2338.992097902097}, {48.6, 
    2417.6206293706296}, {48.8, 2499.507062937063}, {49, 
    2584.0679020979014}, {49.2, 2672.40048951049}, {49.4, 
    2764.2509090909093}, {49.6, 2860.08972027972}, {49.8, 
    2958.8880419580414}, {50, 3061.5296503496506}, {50.2, 
    3167.954475524476}, {50.4, 3279.3267132867136}, {50.6, 
    3394.996363636363}, {50.8, 3514.5386013986017}, {51, 
    3637.8941958041955}, {51.2, 3767.8172727272727}, {51.4, 
    3907.369160839161}, {51.6, 4057.940839160839}, {51.8, 
    4218.387692307691}, {52, 4387.486363636363}, {52.2, 
    4559.219090909091}, {52.4, 4737.994405594407}, {52.6, 
    4926.850629370629}, {52.8, 5133.069790209789}, {53, 
    5351.979300699301}, {53.2, 5580.233216783217}, {53.4, 
    5815.771258741259}, {53.6, 6059.474335664335}, {53.8, 
    6310.2300699300695}, {54, 6566.168951048951}, {54.2, 
    6824.079510489511}, {54.4, 7080.809090909091}, {54.6, 
    7333.146293706293}, {54.8, 7587.8459440559445}, {55, 
    7850.626853146852}, {55.2, 8125.57027972028}, {55.4, 
    8409.073496503495}, {55.6, 8698.83132867133}, {55.8, 
    8996.236433566435}, {56, 9300.716293706295}, {56.2, 
    9614.424195804197}, {56.4, 9936.465874125875}, {56.6, 
    10267.16895104895}, {56.8, 10604.112797202795}, {57, 
    10948.749580419582}, {57.2, 11300.41020979021}, {57.4, 
    11659.683006993006}, {57.6, 12023.626783216785}, {57.8, 
    12392.80202797203}, {58, 12766.768741258744}, {58.2, 
    13147.152517482516}, {58.4, 13533.405594405594}, {58.6, 
    13929.522447552448}, {58.8, 14331.496503496504}, {59, 
    14735.11027972028}, {59.2, 15134.907552447552}, {59.4, 
    15531.639090909091}, {59.6, 15926.898251748251}, {59.8, 
    16319.009370629366}, {60, 16708.945804195802}, {60.2, 
    17100.06636363636}, {60.4, 17496.746923076924}, {60.6, 
    17899.96601398601}, {60.8, 18310.962377622378}, {61, 
    18733.114335664337}, {61.2, 19158.742027972025}, {61.4, 
    19578.491538461538}, {61.6, 19983.563636363637}, {61.8, 
    20383.41286713287}, {62, 20771.78615384616}, {62.2, 
    21143.815874125874}, {62.4, 21493.19979020979}, {62.6, 
    21831.533146853144}, {62.8, 22165.208671328666}, {63, 
    22497.004265734264}, {63.2, 22829.18895104895}, {63.4, 
    23165.61839160839}, {63.6, 23505.106223776227}, {63.8, 
    23845.65895104895}, {64, 24185.918321678324}, {64.2, 
    24530.909580419582}, {64.4, 24870.472797202798}, {64.6, 
    25198.522797202797}, {64.8, 25507.47804195804}, {65, 
    25802.223846153847}, {65.2, 26082.483426573428}, {65.4, 
    26348.033426573424}, {65.6, 26600.166853146857}, {65.8, 
    26840.285384615385}, {66, 27072.183286713287}, {66.2, 
    27294.89937062937}, {66.4, 27510.708951048953}, {66.6, 
    27720.160139860138}, {66.8, 27922.566853146855}, {67, 
    28118.26083916084}, {67.2, 28307.706083916084}, {67.4, 
    28494.77258741259}, {67.6, 28679.58657342657}, {67.8, 
    28860.11972027972}, {68, 29039.42153846154}, {68.2, 
    29210.7306993007}, {68.4, 29366.41545454545}, {68.6, 
    29502.546223776226}, {68.8, 29629.67433566434}, {69, 
    29744.836363636365}, {69.2, 29836.08020979021}, {69.4, 
    29898.33790209791}, {69.6, 29933.56769230769}, {69.8, 
    29959.04762237762}, {70, 29975.020909090912}, {70.2, 
    29991.388531468532}, {70.4, 30006.784055944052}, {70.6, 
    30018.964685314684}, {70.8, 30026.687132867133}, {71, 
    30047.393426573428}, {71.2, 30084.82174825175}, {71.4, 
    30135.9965034965}, {71.6, 30182.328111888113}, {71.8, 
    30225.142167832168}, {72, 30268.663566433566}, {72.2, 
    30319.640629370628}, {72.4, 30372.744545454545}, {72.6, 
    30427.39160839161}, {72.8, 30477.89188811188}, {73, 
    30521.84727272727}, {73.2, 30553.777762237765}, {73.4, 
    30573.294825174824}, {73.6, 30571.749790209793}, {73.8, 
    30562.458741258743}, {74, 30552.884825174824}, {74.2, 
    30553.355174825174}, {74.4, 30564.295454545452}, {74.6, 
    30576.382587412594}, {74.8, 30594.90377622378}, {75, 
    30610.827692307692}, {75.2, 30633.06699300699}, {75.4, 
    30653.350000000002}, {75.6, 30666.33594405594}, {75.8, 
    30668.923426573427}, {76, 30668.75461538462}, {76.2, 
    30670.575314685306}, {76.4, 30670.93328671329}, {76.6, 
    30667.266083916085}, {76.8, 30663.819300699302}, {77, 
    30647.977062937065}, {77.2, 30618.72202797203}, {77.4, 
    30565.47013986014}, {77.6, 30508.620349650355}, {77.8, 
    30455.27230769231}, {78, 30410.724055944054}, {78.2, 
    30383.247272727276}, {78.4, 30363.072377622375}, {78.6, 
    30355.305034965033}, {78.8, 30342.20923076923}, {79, 
    30340.65146853147}, {79.2, 30337.188811188807}, {79.4, 
    30331.158181818184}, {79.6, 30315.162097902103}, {79.8, 
    30295.13181818182}, {80, 30271.48195804196}, {80.2, 
    30250.13118881119}, {80.4, 30224.207062937065}, {80.6, 
    30201.98300699301}, {80.8, 30170.62013986014}, {81, 
    30157.62923076923}, {81.2, 30143.96188811189}, {81.4, 
    30141.00909090909}, {81.6, 30117.328741258738}, {81.8, 
    30092.859790209794}, {82, 30056.212097902095}, {82.2, 
    30011.19230769231}, {82.4, 29951.637552447555}, {82.6, 
    29881.86965034965}, {82.8, 29809.408811188812}, {83, 
    29743.92013986014}, {83.2, 29687.225244755246}, {83.4, 
    29650.274545454547}, {83.6, 29609.51027972028}, {83.8, 
    29570.36111888112}, {84, 29528.284685314688}, {84.2, 
    29495.74104895105}, {84.4, 29464.83104895105}, {84.6, 
    29432.034545454546}, {84.8, 29397.90867132867}, {85, 
    29359.92979020979}, {85.2, 29328.5486013986}, {85.4, 
    29309.78937062937}, {85.6, 29295.625034965036}, {85.8, 
    29279.513916083917}, {86, 29255.218671328672}, {86.2, 
    29234.38566433567}, {86.4, 29227.73384615385}, {86.6, 
    29216.327202797198}, {86.8, 29201.22685314685}, {87, 
    29162.052937062937}, {87.2, 29113.863776223774}, {87.4, 
    29051.34391608391}, {87.6, 28988.94237762238}, {87.8, 
    28926.36160839161}, {88, 28856.33132867133}, {88.2, 
    28782.890699300704}, {88.4, 28712.760769230772}, {88.6, 
    28660.5920979021}, {88.8, 28620.868461538463}, {89, 
    28583.4386013986}, {89.2, 28546.60818181818}, {89.4, 
    28502.005384615386}, {89.6, 28462.87916083916}, {89.8, 
    28422.843076923076}, {90, 28389.142517482516}, {90.2, 
    28339.938461538462}, {90.4, 28275.94958041958}, {90.6, 
    28203.151538461538}, {90.8, 28132.62300699301}, {91, 
    28069.04839160839}, {91.2, 27992.026083916087}, {91.4, 
    27914.222797202798}, {91.6, 27834.239160839163}, {91.8, 
    27766.07118881119}, {92, 27716.52062937063}, {92.2, 
    27679.7613986014}, {92.4, 27652.8013986014}, {92.6, 
    27618.464055944052}, {92.8, 27588.78923076923}, {93, 
    27574.388531468536}, {93.2, 27566.27888111888}, {93.4, 
    27547.25811188811}, {93.6, 27502.117692307693}, {93.8, 
    27444.676573426572}};

ramp1FSmoothFunc[1] = Interpolation[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1]]


ClearAll[helixMidPoint, helixLineLength, helixLowPoint, \
helixLowPointRFU, helixHighPoint, helixHighPointRFU]
ClearAll[coilMidPoint, coilLineLength, coilLowPoint, coilLowPointRFU, \
coilHighPoint, coilHighPointRFU]
ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1];
helixLowBarrier = 10;
helixHighBarrier = 40;
coilLowBarrier = 60;
coilHighBarrier = 90;

{Slider[Dynamic[helixMidPoint], {helixLowBarrier, helixHighBarrier}], 
 Dynamic[helixMidPoint], 
 Dynamic[helixMidPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][helixMidPoint]], 
 Slider[Dynamic[helixLineLength], {5, 25}], Dynamic[helixLineLength]}

{Slider[Dynamic[coilMidPoint], {coilLowBarrier, coilHighBarrier}], 
 Dynamic[coilMidPoint], 
 Dynamic[coilMidPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilMidPoint]], 
 Slider[Dynamic[coilLineLength], {5, 25}], Dynamic[coilLineLength]}

Dynamic[{ListPlot[{ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[
     1], {{helixLowPoint, helixLowPointRFU}}, {{helixHighPoint, 
      helixHighPointRFU}}, {{coilLowPoint, 
      coilLowPointRFU}}, {{coilHighPoint, coilHighPointRFU}}}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Small], PointSize[Large], PointSize[Large],
      PointSize[Large], PointSize[Large]}],

  Grid[{{, "temperature (C)", "Interpolated RFU"}, {"helix low point",
      Dynamic[helixLowPoint = helixMidPoint - helixLineLength/2], 
     Dynamic[helixLowPointRFU = 
       ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][helixLowPoint]]}, {"helix high point", 
     Dynamic[helixHighPoint = helixMidPoint + helixLineLength/2], 
     Dynamic[helixHighPointRFU = 
       ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][
        helixHighPoint]]}, {, ,}, {"coil low point", 
     Dynamic[coilLowPoint = coilMidPoint - coilLineLength/2], 
     Dynamic[coilLowPointRFU = 
       ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilLowPoint]]}, {"coil high point", 
     Dynamic[coilHighPoint = coilMidPoint + coilLineLength/2], 
     Dynamic[coilHighPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilHighPoint]]}},
    Frame -> All]}]

Dynamic[ramp1FBaseLinesTEST = 
  Plot[{ramp1FHelixLinFitEqTEST[temp], 
    ramp1FCoilLinFitEqTEST[temp]}, {temp, 1, 100}]]




Dynamic[ramp1FHelixTEST = 
  Select[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1], 
   helixLowPoint <= #[[1]] <= helixHighPoint &]]

Dynamic[ramp1FHCoilTEST = 
  Select[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1], 
   coilLowPoint <= #[[1]] <= coilHighPoint &]]

Dynamic[ramp1FHelixLinFitTEST = 
  Fit[ramp1FHelixTEST, {1, temp}, temp]]
Dynamic[ramp1FHelixLinFitEqTEST[temp_] = ramp1FHelixLinFitTEST]
Dynamic[ramp1FCoilLinFitTEST = Fit[ramp1FHCoilTEST, {1, temp}, temp]]
Dynamic[ramp1FCoilLinFitEqTEST[temp_] = ramp1FCoilLinFitTEST]
```

Comment: any chance of giving a minimal example with no domain-specific jargon?

Comment: Any specific reason not to choose `Manipulate` here? It will save you enormous amounts of effort. The behaviour of `Dynamic` that you note is by design and is documented. BTW: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Comment: @acl do you mean rephrase the question or replace the "ramp1FHelixLinFitTEST" (etc..) with "a" "b" "c"?  The length of code is part of the problem, dynamic values that need updating are located off-screen.

Comment: I meant that the basic questions seem to be "1) screen refresh needed of output from dynamic values for updating dynamic plots not in the same input section 2) multiple plot types within a single graphic, dynamically". now I know, but it would make more people willing to work that out if you gave a shorter example of these, and avoided mentioning jargon such as "two-state equilibrium process" which may mean different things to different people (I understand you're trying to give background, but in this case I think it just complicates things)

Comment: @SCdV hadn't thought of using Manipulate.  Have no experience with it and reading the manual I thought it was more "closed" in appearance.  Meaning, I thought it was more for manipulating single graphs or plots, and not for changing tables that appear later (based on what's manipulated).  This baseline fitting and subsequent calculations is an hands-on iterative process and I was unsure how to extend Manipulate beyond the scope of the single graphic.  I suppose I should reevaluate the usage of that function....

Comment: @acl OK yea I will word my future posts in more general context.  I was thrown off by the "provide background information on your research" suggestion at the new member welcome screen for posts.  Newb!

Comment: I'd have included it at the end for those interested for what's it worth. As for your first question I don't think Dynamic can be used for that, but would like to see someone prove this wrong.

Comment: Just a tip about pinging commenters: at least the first three letters of their name should follow the @ character. The owner of the post in question will get pinged as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No time to explain the code, but this is more or less what you could do with `Manipulate`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The code (all the code, except for your data definition):

```
ramp1FSmoothFunc[1] = Interpolation[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1]];
{minB, maxB} = Through[{Min, Max}[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1][[All, 1]]]];
DynamicModule[
 {helixLowBarrier = 10,
  helixHighBarrier = 40,
  coilLowBarrier = 60,
  coilHighBarrier = 90,
  helixLowPoint, helixHighPoint, coilLowPoint, coilHighPoint, 
  coilHighPointRFU, coilLowPointRFU, helixHighPointRFU, 
  helixLowPointRFU,
  helixMidPointRFU, coilMidPointRFU, ramp1FHelixTEST, ramp1FHCoilTEST,
   ramp1FHelixLinFitTEST, ramp1FHelixLinFitEqTEST, 
  ramp1FCoilLinFitTEST, ramp1FCoilLinFitEqTEST
  },
 Manipulate[
  helixLowPoint = Clip [helixMidPoint - helixLineLength/2, {minB, maxB}];
  helixHighPoint = Clip[helixMidPoint + helixLineLength/2, {minB, maxB}];
  coilLowPoint = Clip[coilMidPoint - coilLineLength/2, {minB, maxB}];
  coilHighPoint = Clip[coilMidPoint + coilLineLength/2, {minB, maxB}];
  coilHighPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilHighPoint];
  coilLowPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilLowPoint];
  helixHighPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][helixHighPoint];
  helixLowPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][helixLowPoint];
  helixMidPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][helixMidPoint];
  coilMidPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilMidPoint];
  ramp1FHelixTEST = 
    Select[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1], helixLowPoint <= #[[1]] <= helixHighPoint &];
  ramp1FHCoilTEST = 
   Select[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1], coilLowPoint <= #[[1]] <= coilHighPoint &];
  ramp1FHelixLinFitTEST = Fit[ramp1FHelixTEST, {1, temp}, temp];
  ramp1FHelixLinFitEqTEST[temp_] = ramp1FHelixLinFitTEST;
  ramp1FCoilLinFitTEST = Fit[ramp1FHCoilTEST, {1, temp}, temp];
  ramp1FCoilLinFitEqTEST[temp_] = ramp1FCoilLinFitTEST;
  Column[
   {
    Show[
     ListPlot[{ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1], 
               {{helixLowPoint, helixLowPointRFU}}, 
               {{helixHighPoint,helixHighPointRFU}}, 
               {{coilLowPoint, coilLowPointRFU}}, 
               {{coilHighPoint, coilHighPointRFU}}
              }, 
      ImageSize -> Medium, 
      PlotStyle -> 
        {PointSize[Small], PointSize[Large], PointSize[Large], 
         PointSize[Large], PointSize[Large]}
     ],
     Plot[{ramp1FHelixLinFitEqTEST[temp], 
       ramp1FCoilLinFitEqTEST[temp]}, {temp, 1, 100}]
     ],
    Grid[
     {
       {"", "temperature (C)", "Interpolated RFU"},
       {"helix low point", helixLowPoint, helixLowPointRFU},
       {"helix high point", helixHighPoint, helixHighPointRFU},
       {"", "" , ""},
       {"coil low point", coilLowPoint, coilLowPointRFU},
       {"coil high point", coilHighPoint, coilHighPointRFU}
       } // N, Frame -> All
     ]
    }],
  {helixMidPoint, helixLowBarrier, helixHighBarrier, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {helixLineLength, 5, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {coilMidPoint, coilLowBarrier, coilHighBarrier, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {coilLineLength, 5, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  TrackedSymbols -> {helixMidPoint, helixLineLength, coilMidPoint, coilLineLength}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Wow, that is a perfect!  In addition to your lesson on Manipulate there are other things you've pointed out (Show inside Manipulate, Clip instead of Select, Through instead of Part to get high/low values,setting up Dynamic Module).   Thank you greatly SCdV, very appreciative...  I'll read the man on these new functions.  Cheers.